# Laravel Request::secure() function return false

Tags: laravel, ssl

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I'm using a Flexible SSL from Cloudflare.

I have this code on `filters.php` for example:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Request::secure())
        return 'False';
});
```

and when I try to run this on my secured server, I get the `False` Response.
Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Check this: http://laravel.io/forum/06-22-2014-requestsecure-return-false-no-ssl-but-ssl-certificate-is-applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `secure()` function returns false is because the site doesn't really have an SSL Certificate, CloudFlare has. so when the clients connect to the site, the actually connect to CloudFlare (SSL) and CloudFlare connects to the site (Not SSL). So in conclusion, the Request between CloudFlare and the Site is not secured.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I do something wrong here?

Yes. You’re returning a string rather than a boolean. Try this instead:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Request::secure())
        return false;
});
```

I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve, though? If you want to enforce access via SSL, then redirect to the HTTPS version. Returning `false` will just give the user a blank page.

Comment: That wasn't my intention at all. What I was trying to say that even when I have `https` it returns false.