# laravel 5 redirect loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have a redirect loop when deploying my code on heroku but not on my local wamp server. Below is my middleware, its been properly registered. Im using laravel 5, Thanks

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class HttpsEnforcer
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){   
        if(!$request->secure())
        {
            return redirect()->secure($request->path());
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31298765/5641619

Comment: Yes somewhat relevant. But he has no concrete answers there too unfortunately

Comment: Does the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` give you the expected result? I'm guessing that whatever header the `secure()` method checks isn't being set properly by Heroku.

Comment: Run `composer update` on server and see. Sometimes out dated vendors cause this kind of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request::secure()` check `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header for `https`, make sure they are being set.

If you are behind a load balancer which listen to `443` and send traffic on `80` with `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` you will need to use `Request::setTrustedProxies($LB_IP)`

Comment: I think you are on the right track Junaid but im still looping. I have seen some sources with this but it seems like all the examples are in Laravel 4 and I can find setTrustedProxies in the documentation

Comment: So currently if($request->header('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO')!='https') is satisfying the if statement